# Simple modules over R isomorphic to R/I

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, modules, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring, and let $M$ be a simple $R$-Module, meaning that it only has the trivial submodules {0} and $M$. Show that there's a maximal ideal $I \subset R$ so that $M \cong R/I$.

Thanks in advance! I thought that if $I$ is a maximal ideal, then $R/I$ must be a field and therefore only has the trivial ideals, which makes it a simple module. But I'm stuck at that point.

Comment: Why did you ask one question and then write work corresponding to its converse?

Comment: Because that was my (only) approach so far. I couldn't tell much about what a simple R-Module generally looks like, so I tried to first figure out what properties $R/I$ has. If this doesn't seem to be a reasonable approach to the problem for you, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: That is not unreasonable in general. In fact, I use your observation.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement about $I$ maximal is true, and so we see that $R/I$ is simple as an $R$-module.

Also, note that if $J$ is any non-maximal ideal, say $J\subset N\subset R$. Then $N/J$ is a submodule of $R/J$, so $R/J$ is not simple.

Let $M$ be a simple $R$-module. Let $x\in M$ such that there exists $r\in R$ such that $rx \neq 0$. This exists since $M$ is not trivial as an $R$-module.

Since $0\neq Rx\subset M$ is a submodule, then simplicity forces $M = Rx$. Let $I =\{ r\in R : rx = 0\}$ be the annihilator of $x$. Then $Rx \cong R/I$ as $R$-modules.

Thus, $M\cong R/I$, and since $M$ is simple, so is $R/I$, hence $I$ is maximal.

Comment: Thanks! However, why is it that $Rx \cong R/I$?

Comment: Well, I actually tried to figure it out myself: If we consider the homomorphism $f: R → M, r ↦ r m$, it's clearly surjective since Rx = M, therefore the image of f is M. On the other hand, it has the kernel I. Using the homomorphism theorems, it follows that $R/I \cong M$, does it?

Comment: Yes, where you are thinking of $R/I$ as an $R$-module, so the relevant isomorphism theorem is that of modules.